# How do I align text?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

How do I do something like this in LaTeX?

```
X: a, b, c,  
   e, f, g
```

Comment: Is this in math mode or in text mode?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are many ways in which you can produce tabular material; the basic options are the `tabbing` environment, the `tabular` environment, and the `arrray` environment; depending in your intent, you can choose which one to use. Here's a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
X \=  a \= b \= c \\
 \> d \> e \> f
\end{tabbing}

\begin{tabular}{cccc}
  X: & a & b & c \\
  & d & e & f
\end{tabular}

\[
\begin{array}{cccc}
  X: & a & b & c \\
  & d & e & f
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

The above options are explained in any basic LaTeX manual.

Comment: It should be noted that `array` and `tabular` are more or less the same (the use the same internal code), only that `array` defaults to math-mode and `tabular` to text mode.

Comment: Typo: `arrray`?